# Downloading image generated by API from download button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I have this QR code generator that I pieced together from tutorials across the web. You can see it [here](https://troop129.github.io/tarbiya). It replaces an image src in a div with the QR code generated from Google API based on input from the user, so doing  doesn't work, as the link is dynamic. Is there a way to download the image from a button?

I didn't know what part of the code to attach to make it clear, so if you want to see the entire code, visit the GitHub repository: https://github.com/troop129/tarbiya/blob/main/index.html

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only it is possible to 'download the image from a button', but you can also download the image immediately after the API responds and then display it from a local URL.

```js
const url = 'https://picsum.photos/200/300';
const target = document.getElementById('target');
const link = document.getElementById('download');

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener('loadend', (e) => {
  const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.response);
  target.src = blobUrl;
  link.href = blobUrl;
  link.download = 'image.jpg';
});

xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

```html
<img id='target'></img>
<a id='download'>Download</a>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried adding that into my code, but it is not working, can you take a look? https://codepen.io/troop129/pen/VwKEbBv

Comment: @AbidRasheed already did. Sorry if I took the liberty of copying and modifying your code. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/ernestostifano/om8gf2bc/8/ for a working version. I also removed jQuery (I recommend you to completely drop it. As you will be able to see, modern JavaScript can be more clear and direct than jQuery which I consider obsolete). Please let me know if you have any doubt!

Comment: I have one problem, how can I make it download as the name.png? right now it is just doing qr.png

Comment: @AbidRasheed just replace `download.download = 'qr.png';` with `download.download = \`${data.name}.png\`;`

Comment: yes i figured it out thank you but there is a problem. The QR is supposed to generate "name,phone,email" but it is adding symbols that is not supposed to be there. It is generating a QR that says  ```%7B%22name%22%3A%22Abid%22%2C%22phone%22%3A%221234567890%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22abid%40gmail.com%22%7D``` instead of ```abid,1234567890,abid@gmail.com```

Comment: @AbidRasheed do you need the content to be Human Readable or you need it to be used by other software after being scanned?

Comment: I have another scanning app on android, which reads and uploads the data to a google sheet. It takes in the data as human readable, "name,phone,email"